# SQL Server Order By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to order my returned dataset by first the specified value and then by ascending order.  For example:

```
Declare @Value varchar(55)
Set @Value = 'abc'

Select ID, Value
From Table1
Order by ID ASC
```

I want to make sure that first my 'abc' value prints out on the first row, then the rest of the dataset should be sorted by ID in ascending order.  Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. If your IDs start with 1, 2, 3.... etc. you can use this query:

```
Select ID, Value
From Table1
Order by CASE WHEN value = @value then 0 else ID END ASC
```